# Why I cannot take a value from a website using seleniun

Tags: python, html, selenium

I want to get the datum called "value" in the next HTML structure

[image]

[image]

I have tried many things such as `driver.find_element_by_id('date')`  but I knew that is not going to work because there many ids with the same name.

I have seen in tutorials how this can be done but in these sources, they put very easy examples. In this case, I don't know how to get that date.

Comment: Have you tried xpath or css selectors? I guess you have no influence on the appearance of the web page?

Comment: I am going to have a look at these xpath or css selectors. Why did you ask if I have influence in the appearance? The thing is that that is my dashboard but it is done with dash so yes

Comment: With influence I meant if you develop the page and can change it so it is proper HTML

Comment: This also looks like a duplicate that has been answered on this page at least a dozen times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to get the element by classname and use get_attribute('value') to get the date value

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//input[contains(@class,'DateInput_input')]").get_attribute("value")
```

Comment: if there is an identical item how can I take the second one. I mean with identical html structure?

Comment: can you share the html for the element you are talking about?

Comment: I have added a second image in which you can see both

Comment: BTW I guess there are several Date inputs there. If so we have to select accordingly to 'DateInput_input_1' class name here

Comment: See if this works - driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//input[@class='DateInput_input DateInput_input_1']").get_attribute("value")

Comment: both get same value I mean "01/27/2021"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="DateInput DateInput_1"]/input').get_attribute("value")
```